# How to make Update Mutation - GraphQL (plus mongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

I would like to do an update mutation to albums, but I'm having issues getting the update and getting the return value.

Schema Mongoose:

```
var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    dateUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

GraphQL Type:

```
    const AlbumType = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Album',
        fields: () => ({
            id: {type:GraphQLID},
            name: {type:GraphQLString},
            dateCreated: {type: GraphQLString},
            dateUpdated: {type: GraphQLString}
        })
    })
```

Update Mutation:

```
updateAlbum: { //STILL TRYING TO GET TO WORK
            type: AlbumType,
            args: {
                id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                name: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
            },
            resolve(parentValue, args){
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    ALBUM.findOneAndUpdate(
                        {id: args.id},
                        {name: args.name},
                        //{dateUpdated:  Date.now()}
                    ).exec((err, res) => {
                        if(err) reject(err)
                        else resolve()
                    })
                })
            }
        }
```

Test Mutation:

```
mutation {
  updateAlbum(id:"5a695c586c050802f182270c", name: "album 333"){
    id
   name }}
```

Test Mutation's Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateAlbum": null
  }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How should I write the `updateAlbum` function?
2. (less important) How do I add the `Date.now()` to get a new `dateUpdated:` value?
3. How do I get the return value or what ever it is that I can get a response that isn't `updateAlbum: null`? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. See Below. You need to add the "$set" to put the set of parameters you will be changing.

```
    updateAlbum: {
                type: AlbumType,
                args: {
                    id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                    name: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
                },
                resolve(parentValue, args){
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const date = Date().toString()
                        ALBUM.findOneAndUpdate(
                            {"_id": args.id},
                            { "$set":{name: args.name, dateUpdated: date}},
                            {"new": true} //returns new document
                        ).exec((err, res) => {
                            console.log('test', res)
                            if(err) reject(err)
                            else resolve(res)
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
```

2. The date needs to be made into a string, keep with Date() instead of Date.now() to leave same as mongoose format.
3. See above, you need to add `res` into `resolve()`